# Developing a distribution and multiplying by random envelope

Tags: random, inverse-function, gaussian

I realize this does not make sense what I'm trying to do below *. So I am rephrasing:
I have data that takes on values from [-1,1] heavily centred around zero, say distributed Gaussian about 0.  I have other data that goes from [1,2.5] but distributed as an inverse curve say 1/x^2.

If I am multiplying individual data points' values, they will span [-2.5,2.5], but how will they be distributed?  It does not seem I can just fit two curves and multiply them.  Should I make two distributions for a large number of data and then just multiply and fit?  there seems there should be an analytical approach.

Make sense?

*
I have two variables with distributions.  The first (A) will be something like a unit Gaussian centred on zero, taking values in x -1 to +1, but noisy.  The second (B) looks like a steep inverse function, say taking values from x = 1, y=1 to x= 2.5, y=very close to zero descending monotonically along the x-axis.  I want to multiply these and see what my distribution would look like.  Is it simply gaussian*(1/x^a)?  I know the bounded function would have unit height and domain -2.5 to 2.5, but is that all there is to it?  Is there a way to better describe it's shape mathematically?  See the attached image.
[distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9G5V.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No bites?

I think that I can do this to accomplish the same, though it is not the exact same thing.
I can multiply the Pareto (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) or shifted chi-sqr, or ... distributions, and regenerate the numbers.